# My woocommerce cart items delete not working properly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

all i have a serious problem regarding the woocommerce cart system. My cart items are not deleting all the time and for all the products, sometime it deletes and remove but sometimes it doesn't.

It seems which products we first added to cart is not deleting every time.

https://amplefoodstore.com.au/ this is the website url. I have used default WP theme if it's causing because of themes WooCommerce files, also deleted all the WooCommerce plugins directory from plugins and added fresh woocommerce files. But no luck over there.

Comment: Looks like caching issue to me.

Comment: I have deleted all the cache directory too and tried many times on different browsers. But no luck

Comment: Can you check template files if you have override them or your functions.php for any custom code made? Try activate a default theme to see if its a theme issue.